# Calling a method annotated with @Cacheable (org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable)

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-security, spring-cache

When calling a method annotated with @Cacheable (org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable), that exists in a different(third party) project causes the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'usersCache' for CacheableOperation[public com.epsilon.amp.infra.model.AuthUser com.epsilon.amp.infra.dao.ContextDao.loadContextUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] caches=[usersCache] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless=''
```

The annotation over the method on the third party project is as follows

```
@Cacheable("usersCache")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
```

Adding annotations and enabling caching in my project doesn't fix the problem. What could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you to create a Configuration like that :

```
@Configuration
public class CacheService extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
            @Override
            protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
                return new ConcurrentMapCache(name,
                        CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(100).build().asMap(), false);
            }
        };
        return cacheManager;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager guavaCacheManager() {
        return new GuavaCacheManager();
    }
}
```

After that, you must add this annotation at the head of your class you want to cache method.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "guavaCacheManager")
```

And at the head of your Application class this annotation : `@EnableCaching`

Guava info : https://github.com/google/guava